# How can I save zoomed scale for multiple images using interactive view in flutter?

Tags: flutter, view, interactive

I actually need to set scale on multiple images to be cropped together later, I'm using Cropperx library, which can crop the image one bye one, but I want something like Bumble dating app does.

```
               Cropper(

                cropperKey: _cropperKey,
                overlayType: _overlayType,
                rotationTurns: _rotationTurns,
                transformationController: viewTransformationController,
            
                image: selectedPhoto == null?Image.file(File(imageList[0])):Image.file(File(selectedPhoto!.path))  ,
                onScaleStart: (details) {

                  // todo: define started action.

                },
                onScaleUpdate: (details) {

                  // todo: define updated action.
                },
                onScaleEnd: (details) {
             

                  // todo: define ended action.
                },
              )
```

LimitedBox(
maxHeight: 300,
child: GridView.builder(
itemCount: imageList.length,
gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
crossAxisCount: 4,
childAspectRatio: .75
),
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
return GestureDetector(
onTap: () {
setState(() {
selectedPhoto = File(imageList[index]);
imageIndex = index;
print(imageIndex);
});
},
child: Stack(children: [

```
                          Image.file(
                          File(imageList[index]), fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                          Radio(
                              activeColor: kRedColor,
                              value: 1, groupValue: 0, onChanged: (value){}),],

                        ));
                  }),
            )
```